# Starting RAID array manually

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid, maintenance

Is there any way to start a RAID array manually without rebooting after stopping it via `mdadm -S`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can just *assemble* the array:

```bsh
$ sudo mdadm -A /dev/md/N
```

This will put it in a running state, assuming `mdadm` could automatically detect the member devices by scanning the partitions that are known to the kernel.

The `--scan` option will also allow `mdadm` to search configuration files for missing information needed to assemble the array.

Finally, to also start an array assembled with fewer drives than the last time the array has been active, you can use the `--run` option.

Note that, depending on your setup, you may then need to mount the array. It is usually enough to run:

```bsh
$ sudo mount --all
```

assuming that the array is mentioned in your `fstab`.